# Sort ArrayList of objects that are instance of sub classes of abstract class

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, comparable

this my main structure:
Some of the interface methods are implemented in class A, all the rest are implemented in sub classes.

```
public interface I
{
// some methods
//
}
```

---

```
public abstract class A implements I
{
// some variables and methods
//
}
```

---

```
public class B extends A
{
// some variables and methods
//
}
```

---

```
public class C extends A
{
// some variables and methods
//
}
```

---

```
public abstract class D extends A
{
// some variables and methods
//
}
```

---

```
public class E extends D
{
// some variables and methods
//
}
```

---

```
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  ArrayList<I> la = new ArrayList<I>();
  la.add(new B(..));
  la.add(new C(..));
  la.add(new C(..));
  la.add(new B(..));
  la.add(new E(..));
 }
}
```

There are constructors in B, C and E classes.

I need to sort `la` by variable of class A, the variable is int data type.

I try to change to

```
public abstract class A implements I, Comparable<A>
```

But I get an error because of missing `public int compareTo(A o)`  method in all nonabstract classes.

What I need to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: If some thing is missing then how is the idea of adding the missing entity.

Comment: Sorting of objects of your classes is something based on your logic. JVM can not magically define it for you. You need to define it some where. If you implement Comparable interface then you need to define the comparision logic in the implwmwntation of its abstract method `compareTo` You have to provide the implementation for the method. Add it , implement the logic for comparision. May be either you will be able to solve the issue or you will have more *meaningful* and *specific* question.

Comment: so I need to implement 
    
public int compareTo(A o)

in class A ?

Comment: If you can, implement it in `A`, then you need to write it only once. You might alternatively implement in `B`, `C` and `E`, or just override it in one of those classes, but I cannot readily imagine why you would want to or need to.

Comment: How can I implement  this method only in `class A`.
I don't have a constructor in `class A` so I don't know how to that.

in void main I'm using `Collections.sort`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class A implements I, Comparable<A> {
    // some variables and methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return someVariable - o.someVariable;
    }
}
```

You don't need no constructor in A to implement a `compareTo` method, and you have got some variables you may use for comparison. `compareTo` is just a method, so since you can have methods in A, you can also have a `compareTo` method. Since I don't know what varables you've got nor the sort order you require, you will have to fill out the method yourself.

On the other hand it could well be a good idea to have a constructor in A, but this is a completely independent question.

Edit: I didn’t think this through at first: you will of course want to do

```
    Collections.sort(la);
```

This is not as straightforward as it may sound. `Collections.sort()` is a generic method declared according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) as:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

This means that for the compiler to be happy about a call to the method, the declared element type of the list must be one that implements `Comparable<U>` for some type `U` that is either the element type or a supertype of it. Your element type is `I`, and `I` doesn’t implement `Comparable`. This is why you get the error message.

The solution? I don’t think the perfect solution exists. Assuming you don’t want to declare `la` an `ArrayList<A>`, another option is to declare that `I` is comparable:

```
public interface I extends Comparable<I>
```

Strictly speaking this is promising more about `A` than we can fulfil. We can compare two `A` objects (even when they are instances of subclasses of `A`), but there might be other implementations of `I`, and we may not know how to compare them to `A`. One way out is:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(I o) {
    A oa = (A) o; // will throw ClassCastException if o is not an A
    return someVariable - oa.someVariable;
}
```

Since `A` extends `I` and `I` extends `Comparable<I>`, we now have to declare `o` an `I`, not an `A`. If somebody gives us some foreign `I` implementation, we throw a `ClassCastException`, and the sorting would propagate that to the caller. However, we know that in your list all elements are instances of subclasses of `A`, so this won’t happen. With the above, both your call to `S.sortBySome()` and its call to `Collections.sort()` will work.

Comment: I add this method to class A.
The arraylist `la` from the main, I pass it to a static method from another class in the package.
In the main method I use foreach to print all the instances in sorted order by some variable.
`public class S
{
 public static ArrayList<String> sortBySome(ArrayList<I> la)
 {
 } 
}
`
so I add this to the method:
`  ArrayList<String> obj = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  Collections.sort(la);
`
But I get an error on sort method.
`The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<I>)`
Why is that?

Comment: I get the same error message. See my edit for an explanation and one way to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding 
`public interface I extends Comparable<I>`
and in class A I changed the method `compareTo` to

```
public int compareTo(I obj)
{
    return someVariable - obj.someVariable;
}
```